# What's best practice in this situation?

Tags: asp.net, oop

I was just writing a small asp.net web page to display a collection of objects by binding to a repeater, when this came to mind.

Basically the class I've created, let's call it 'Test', has a price property that's an integer data type (ignore the limitations of using this type, I'm just using it as an example). However I want to format this property so it displays a currency and the correct decimal places etc.

Is it best practice to have a function within the class that returns the formatted string for the object, or would it be better to have a function in the back end of my web form that operations on the object and returns the formatted string?

I've heard before that a class should contain all it's relative functions but I've also heard that presentation should be kept in the 'presentation layer' in my N-tier app.

What would be the best approach in my situation? (and apologies if I haven't explained this clearly enough!)

Thanks!

Comment: This should be a helper method. Since the situation you talk about is for a commonly-known formatting, I would create a helper class to hold such common methods and use that helper class' methods to get the formatted string. The input value to the helper method should be provided directly from the data instance. If you add such a formatting method to the data class, you take step #1 towards pollution of the data class - down the road you would be tempted to add more such formatting methods for other data members. Keep the `toCurrency` etc out of there. Just my thoughts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, both options are valid from an OO point of view.

- Since the value *is* a price (that just happens to have the wrong data type), it makes sense to put the formatting into the data class. It's not something that's specific to the web interface, and, if you develop a different kind of user interface, you are very likely to require this formatting again.
- On the other hand, it's a presentation issue, so it also makes sense to put it into the presentation layer.

Comment: I suppose this is why I'm getting so confused, ha!

Answer (score 1):

For general OOP stuff, the object should not be exposing implementation details.  I choose to interpret this as "avoid setters and getters when possible".

In the context of your question, I suggest that you have a getPriceDisplay() method that returns a string containing the formatted price.

The actual implementation of the formatting is hidden in the implementation details.  You could provide a generic function for formatting, use some backend call, or something else.  Those details should make no difference to the consumer of the 'Test' object.

Comment: So you think the getPriceDisplay() function should be within my 'Test' class? or in my web form's code behind?

I imagine it'd make more sense to put it within my 'Test' class but I'm not sure. Thanks for your help anyway :-)

Comment: The manner in which price is stored within Test is an implementation detail.  The means by which price is formatted into a currency display value is an implementation details.  Both belong in the Test class or (as Heinzi mentioned) in a presentation layer class for the Test model class.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's not an OOP approach, in my opinion, this is a good time for an extension method. Call it `.ToCurrency()` which has the format of the currency...this could be taken from the Web.Config file if you wanted.

**Edit**

To elaborate, I would simply call `.ToString("your-format")` (of course this could be as simple as `.ToString("C")` for your specific question) in the extension method. This allows you change the format throughout the UI in one place. I have found this to be very useful when dealing with `DateTime` formats in web applications.

Comment: Actually I _think_ .net allows you to convert to currency using the .ToString() method but I'm not 100% sure. I wasn't actually trying to find out how to convert to currency.. just using it as an example, but thanks! :-)

Comment: @alimac83 You are correct, you can use the .ToString("your-format") and my suggestion is to use that under the extension method actually. This way if the format needs to change for whatever reason, everywhere you display it, you will be calling the extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `.ToString("C");` do the job? This would be in the presentation layer I would imagine.